# How to create div element inside div element with labels properly positioned

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a rather unusual challenge where I have to create a div inside div (inception situation) where a number of inner elements are not fixed but depend on the collection of objects fetched from db.

I've found the solution to center the div inside the div, even handling the color gradient but the final issue remains and that is how to handle labels (numbers and descriptions as seen in image below)

But let's say that the expected element count should not be higher than five.
For the purpose of this demo/question let's say we 3 elements.

The final solution should look something like this:

[image]

To be honest, I'm stuck since I don't know how to handle the descriptions and numerical values and let alone the arrow that points to the inner div with the numerical values inside it.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #DCDCDC;
}

.box-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #DCDCDC;
  filter: brightness(0.90);
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

.box-2 {
  background: #DCDCDC;
  filter: brightness(0.90);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="box-1">
    <span>Nu 100</span>
    <span>Nu 100</span>
    <span>Inner div description</span>
    <div class="box-2">
      <span>Nu 101</span>
      <span>Nu 202</span>
      <span>Inner div longer description</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this help.

```css
main {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
}

main label {
    position: absolute;
}

.top_label {
    top: 15px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.left_label {
    top: 50%;
    left: 15px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
}

.bottom_label {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}

.box {
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
}

.box._1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.box._2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
}

.box._3 {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: rgb(155, 155, 155);
}

.arrow {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.arrow_head {
    position: absolute;
    right: -7px;
    top: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.arrow p {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    text-align: right;
}

.arrow._1 {
    top: 75px;
    width: 65px;
}

.arrow._2 {
    top: 0;
    left: 30px;
    width: 110px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="arrow _1">
        <p>85</p>
        <div class="arrow_head"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow _2">
        <p>133</p>
        <div class="arrow_head"></div>
    </div>
    <label class="top_label">0</label>
    <label class="left_label">0</label>
    <div class="box _1">
        <label class="top_label">96</label>
        <label class="left_label">0</label>
        <label class="bottom_label">OUTER DIV</label>
        <div class="box _2">
            <label class="top_label">37</label>
            <label class="left_label">85</label>
            <label class="bottom_label">INNER DIV</label>
            <div class="box _3">
                <label class="bottom_label" style="white-space: nowrap;">CENTER DIV WITH LONGER DESCRIPTION</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: This is a solution that I've been looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute positioning to achieve the required result.

```css
#inner, #innermost, #outer, #outermost{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

#outermost{
  width: 350px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #f1f1f0;
}

#outer{
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #dadad9; 
}

#inner{
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #c6c6c5;
}

#innermost{
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #B5B5B4;
}

.desc{
  z-index: 999;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25px;
}

.dimension-top{
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}

.dimension-left{
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.label{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: white;
}

.label-left{
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 75px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 75px;
}

.label-top{
  z-index: 9999;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  top: 25px;
  left: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="outermost">
    <div class="label label-top">133</div>
    <div class="label label-left">85</div>
    <span class="dimension-top">0</span>
    <span class="dimension-left">0</span>
    <span class="desc">OUTER DIV</span>
    <div id="outer">
      <span class="dimension-top">96</span>
      <span class="dimension-left">0</span>
      <span class="desc">INNER DIV</span>
      <div id="inner">
        <span class="dimension-top">37</span>
        <span class="dimension-left">85</span>
        <span class="desc">CENTER DIV WITH LONGER DESCRIPTION</span>
        <div id="innermost">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I believe that this answers my question. Thank you. To be honest i still don't know how to create an arrows from the div element but ill try to figure something out :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this helps.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #DCDCDC;
}

.box {
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
text-align: center;
}
.description{
 justify-self:flex-end;
 order:3;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="box">
    <span>Nu 100</span>
    <span>Nu 100</span>
    <span class="description">Outer div</span>
    <div class="box">
      <span>Nu 101</span>
      <span>Nu 202</span>
      <span class="description">Inner div </span>
     <div class="box">
      <span>Nu 101</span>
      <span>Nu 202</span>
      <span class="description">Innermost div</span>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```